# Replace keys in string by value based on key–value entries in object

Tags: javascript, string, replace, javascript-objects

I’m trying to convert each integer in a string to its corresponding value in an object based on its key–value entries. For example if I have:

```js
var arr = {
    "3": "value_three",
    "6": "value_six",
    "234": "other_value"
  };
var str = "I want value 3 here and value 234 here";
```

I would expext the output to be:

```js
new_str = "I want value_three here and value other_value here"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm just doing this off the top of my head, but this should work.

```
var new_str = str;

for (var key in arr) {
    if (!arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }

    new_str = new_str.replace(key, arr[key]);
}
```

If you wanted all occurrences of the number to be replaced, you'd need to incorporate a Regex into the mix:

```
var new_str = str;

for (var key in arr) {
    if (!arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }

    new_str = new_str.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), arr[key]);
}
```

Also, I'd pick another name other than `arr`, as that implies it's an array when it's clearly an object. Also, make sure you only use `for-in` loops on objects, not arrays, because of issues with prototype leakage and others.

You can also do this with jQuery, but it's probably overkill:

```
var new_str = str;

$.each(arr, function (key, value) {
    new_str = new_str.replace(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the usage of the variable names was trying to use a simple example. I continue to get a typeerror though when trying to use the replace method, do I need to type cast the key or something similar?

Comment: Forget that, I worked it out. Thank you very much for your help and prompt response. Quick question, why is the jquery version overkill?

Comment: Because there is nothing in jQuery to help with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an object like `arr`, with `str` defined and `new_str` declared. Then, assuming that we aim for a general solution the following works:

```js
var arr = { "3": "value_three", "6": "value_six", "234": "other_value" };
var str = "I want value 3 here and value 234 here";

// Building a regex like `/3|6|234/g`
let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(arr).join('|'), 'g');

// Arrow function is approximately equivalent to
// an anonymous function like `function(match) { return arr[match]; }`
new_str = str.replace(re, match => arr[match]);

console.log(new_str);
```

Just as a little side note, `arr` given your example is an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). (I realize that they are sometimes called associative arrays as well; just pointing it out).

Comment: Very nice, but not completely correct output. You have `value value_three` instead of just `value_three` but I like it. Surprised it does not replace `234` with `2value_three4`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a reducer here which looks cleaner in my opinion:

```
new_str = Object.keys(dynamicValues).reduce((prev, current) => {
  return prev.replace(new RegExp(current, 'g'), dynamicValues[current]);
}, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

2021:

Do take care that

```
value 3
```

also matches

```
value 32
```

```js
const arr = {'3':'value_three', '6':'value_six', '234':'other_value'};
let str = 'I want value 3 here and value 234 here';

Object.keys(arr).forEach(key => str = str.replaceAll(`value ${key}`,arr[key]))
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex`, an alternative solution could be like this:

```js
const object = {
    "3": "value_three",
    "6": "value_six",
    "234": "other_value"
};
const str = "I want value 3 here and value 234 here. value 32";

const replacedText1 = str.replace(/value \d+/g, v=>object[v.split(" ")[1]] || v);

const replacedText2 = str.replace(/\d+/g, v=>object[v] || v);

console.log(replacedText1);
console.log(replacedText2);
```

Comment: Change the 12 to 3 and run again. Only one of them work - he wants `value 3` but then we must take care of `value 32` too

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to replace a string with `key: value` entries of an object, where some keys contain special characters such as curly brackets. So, as others have suggested we can use the `String.replace` function with a RegExp passing a function as the replacement value, but there's a problem with creating a RegExp itself, since we would need to escape all special characters in it with `\`. Here's the escaping function and the final replacement function with an example:

```js
// Escape string to use it in a regular expression
const regexpEscape = (string) => string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

// Replace string with `key: value` entries of the search object.
const stringReplace = (string, search) => {
  const regexp = new RegExp(
    Object.keys(search)
      .map((item) => regexpEscape(item))
      .join('|'),
    'g'
  );
  return string.replace(regexp, (match) => search[match]);
};

const search = {
   '{{name}}': 'John',
   '{{lastname}}': 'Doe',
   '{{age}}': 24,
};

const template = 'Hey, {{name}} {{lastname}}! Your age is {{age}}.';

console.log(stringReplace(template, search));
```

Hope it helps somebody! Stay safe :)